# Displaying a different page when admin logs in

Tags: php, session, authentication, login-script

I have created a login on my homepage which allows a user to login, then it redirects them to their user page. However, I'm trying to display a different page only for the admin? This is my code for my login

`shoeshomepage.php`

```
// Check if we have already created a authenticated session 

?><!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Sassy Shoes Homepage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="gumby/css/gumby.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<p><IMG class="displayed" src="heels.png" alt="Logo">

<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="shoeshomepage.php">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="womens.php">HERS</a>
<li><a href="mens.php">HIS</a>
<li><a href="kids.html">KIDS</a>
<li><a href="contact_us.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<br class="clearboth"/> 
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["authenticatedUserEmail"])) { 

echo "<br /><div id=\"container\"><div id=\"sidebar\"><h3><font color=red>".$_SESSION["message"]           = "You are already logged in as ". $_SESSION['authenticatedUserEmail']."</font><br /><a     href=\"loginadmin.php\">Edit Account |</a><a href=\"logout.php\">  Logout</a></h3></div></div>"; //Output any the error message

}else{

?><div id="container"><h3>
<div id="sidebar1">


<br />

<form action="loginaction.php" method="post">
Email:  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
<a href="forgot.php">Forgot Password? |</a>
<a href="register.php">Register </a> <br />
<?php 

echo "<h3><font color=red>".$_SESSION['message']."</font></h3>"; //Output any the error message - 
?>

</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

`loginaction.php`This is my loginaction.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

include_once ("connection.php");

// Get the data collected from the user

$email = trim($_POST["email"]);

$password = trim($_POST["password"]);


//Check for errors

if (empty($email) or empty($password)) {

$_SESSION["message"] = "Must enter Email and Password ";

header("Location: shoeshomepage.php");  //Redirection information

exit ;//Ends the script

}

$email = strip_tags($email);

$password = strip_tags($password);


//Create and run a query with the given details

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email= '$email' AND  Password = '$password' ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or exit("Error in query: $query. " . mysqli_error());


// see if any rows were returned

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {//Then we have a successful login

//Create a session variable to store the user name.

$_SESSION["authenticatedUserEmail"] = $email;

//We could also use information drawn from the database eg ID

$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
//This could be used later to get more information

// Relocate to the logged-in page

header("Location: loginadmin.php");

} else {//Login was unsuccesful

$_SESSION["message"] = "Could not login as $email";

header("Location: shoeshomepage.php");//Go back to the login pages

} //End else
?>
```

`loginadmin.php`this is my user page (its not meant to be called loginadmin.php)

```
// Check if we have established an authenticated

if (!isset($_SESSION["authenticatedUserEmail"])) {

$_SESSION["message"] = "You must be logged in to see this user page. Please Login";

header("Location: shoeshomepage.php");

//Go back and login

}

//If this page hasn't been redirected (we are allowed in) then we can display

?> 

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Sassy Shoes Homepage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="gumby/css/gumby.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<p><IMG class="displayed" src="heels.png" alt="Logo">

<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="shoeshomepage.php">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="women_shoes.php">HERS</a>

<li><a href="mens.php">HIS</a>
<li><a href="kids.html">KIDS</a> 
<li><a href="contact_us.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
<br class="clearboth"/>
</div>


<div id="container"><h3>
<div id="sidebar1" width="40%">&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<?php
echo "Welcome to your profile,  " . $_SESSION['username'] . ".";?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p> 

</div></h3>
<br />
<h1>Your details</h1> 
<br />
<table border= "3" style="width:60%; margin:auto">
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td><?php echo $_SESSION['username'] . "</p>";?></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><?php echo $_SESSION['first_name'] . "</p>";?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td><?php echo $_SESSION['last_name'] . "</p>";?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email Address</td>
<td><?php echo $_SESSION["authenticatedUserEmail"] . "</p>";?></td>
</tr>
</table>


</div>
<hr />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to use `session_start()` before you can access the `$_SESSION` variables. So your `isset()` will always return false.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the type of user in your db e.g. normal user, admin user, etc.
On successful match of the email and password, fetch the `type of user` and if it is admin, redirect it to the admin page using `header("Location: [page for admin].php");`

**Edit**

Add a column in your database called `user_type`. Add `0` for the user who is admin and `1` for the normal user.
In your `php` script, you can add the following line:

`$user_type = $row['user_type'];`

after

`$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];`

After fetching all the session variables, you can do

```
if($user_type == 0)
  header("Location: adminpage.php");

else
  header("Location: adminpage.php");
```

Comment: How would I fetch the type of user? Sorry I'm new to PHP!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to store user type in database, than you can use if statement to show the correct page.   something like this:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['usertype'];

if ($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'admin'){
    header("Location: adminpage.php");
} else {
    header("Location: loginadmin.php");
}
```

Always validate the `$_SESSION['usertype']` in your pages to make sure that no commom users can access admin pages.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! I have one small issue however... I am trying to make sure only admins can access this page even if the url is typed in... I tried 'if (isset($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'normal')){ 

$_SESSION["message"] = "You must be an admin in to see this user page.";

header("Location: shoeshomepage.php");' but it comes up with errors

Comment: okay so I have managed to stop normal users from accessing the page. However when someone who hasn't logged in tries it, it comes up with the correct echo 'no access' but it comes up undefined variable 'usertype' how can i make this go away?

Comment: have you included `session_start();` before call $_SESSION?  How are you validating if user is not logged in?